# Remove row from multidimensional array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```
String[][] qArray = new String[][] {
  {"question", "answerOption1", "answerOption2", "answerOption3", "answerOption4"}
  {"question", "answerOption1", "answerOption2", "answerOption3", "answerOption4"}
}
```

I assign the question text to a TextView and the andswerOptions to text on Buttons. The order is randomly selected, so because the question isnt supposed to be asked twice, i need to remove the question just asked. What i have read i need to delete this array and create a new one, but i'm not quite sure how this is done. I'm not sure how the for syntax is in Java, but here is my guess:

Assuming the question asked is held in TextView tv

```
String[][] newArray = new String[qArray.length-1][5] {
For rows in qArray do newArray.addRow
  if (qArray[0..qArray.length][0] != tv.getText());
qArray = newArray
```

And then redoing the methods again untill there are no more questions left.

Answer (score 0):

A queue is meant for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[][] qArray = new String[][]
        {
            {"question", "answerOption1", "answerOption2", "answerOption3", "answerOption4"},
            {"question5", "answerOption6", "answerOption7", "answerOption8", "answerOption9"}
        };

        Queue<String[]> list = new LinkedList<String[]>(Arrays.asList(qArray));
        for (String[] theArr = list.poll() ; theArr!=null ; theArr = list.poll())
        {
            for (String theStr : theArr)
            {
                System.out.print(theStr + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a for loop implementation. why not use something like this

```
String[][] newArray = new String[qArray.length][5];
for(int i=0; i<=qArray.length-1; i++){
 for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
    newArray[i][j] = qArray[i][j];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String[][] qArray = new String[][]{
                {"question", "answerOption1", "answerOption2", "answerOption3", "answerOption4"},
                {"question5", "answerOption6", "answerOption7", "answerOption8", "answerOption9"}
            };

            List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>(Arrays.asList(qArray));
            list.remove(1);//row that needs to be deteted
            String[][] qArray1 = list.toArray(new String[][]{});
            for (String[] arr : qArray1) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            }

    }
```